# Is there such a thing as an array of Lists in C#

Tags: generics

I have a class that has a constructor of 4 lists like:

```
Public MyClass(List<MyObjA> ObjAs, List<MyObjB> ObjBs,etc.)
```

I want to use reflection to determine the contents of each list by checking the first item of the IList and do some processing.  I could do this by checking each IList but it would be better if I could just pass an array of ILists that way I could just iterate through the array but this won't work as each IList passed in has a specific generic type passed in (e.g. MyObjA or MyObjB, etc.).  The only thing I can think of is passing in an array of objects like:

```
MyClassWithObjArrayConstructor a = new MyClassWithObjArrayConstructor(new object[ObjAs,ObjBs,ObjCs,ObjDBs]);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

How about passing in a `List<List<BaseObj>`?

Where all of your 4 object types inherit from BaseObj. Then, using reflection you could do your processing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to rethink this a bit, MyClass looks way too broad if it's being instantiated with multiple lists of different unknown objects types.

I would have a class that either dealt with a list of one type of predefined object, or a class that still only dealt with only one type of object but make it use generics.